# How can an e-mail database be structured so as to facilitate multi-dimensional search, such as by sender, by receiver, by subject and by time?

Tags: database, information-retrieval

e-mail database is a database that stores a large number of electronic mail messages. It can be viewed as a semi structured database consisting mainly of text data.

How can such an e-mail database be structured so as to facilitate multi-dimensional search, such as by sender, by receiver, by subject and by time?

Answer (score 0):

How can the entire internet be structured for search?

Use search engine technology.

The key technique are inverted indexes.